# Sonata Admin: Add new field to Post Entity

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I am planning to use Sonata Admin for one of my projects, so for now i am testing its features. I would like to add a new field to Sonata's Post entity (SonataNewsBundle).

**For example I want to add a new check-box (called "breaking"), for news marked as Breaking news.**

Sonata Admin is a great piece of software, but *it really lacks documentation*. I've looked to docs on the official site, but i have no clue what should I do to accomplish this task.

What are **the steps** to add a new boolean field (breaking) to Sonata Admin Post entity? **How** can i do this?

**Thank you in advance.**

---

*P.S.: I have attached a standard Sonata Admin screenshot with **existing "enabled" field**. I would like to have a **similar field for news marked as breaking**. I do not need to use the tag (or any other classification system) or the category based classification - just a check-box that would mark or unmark the Post entity as breaking.*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"--- > You have to add your boolean field to your entity Where i should add this field"
For example:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $description;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="bool")
    */
   protected $isVisible;
}
```

In your Admin class:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Admin/ProductAdmin.php

namespace AppBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;

class ProductAdmin extends Admin
{
    // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('name', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Product Name'
            ))
            ->add('price', 'decimal', array(
                'label' => 'Product Price'
            ))

            // if no type is specified, SonataAdminBundle tries to guess it
            ->add('description')
            ->add('isVisible', 'bool', array(
                'label' => 'Is Product visible'
            ))

            // ...
       ;
    }
    // Fields to be shown on filter forms
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
   $datagridMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('price')
   ;
}

// Fields to be shown on lists
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('name')
        ->add('price')
   ;
}

// Fields to be shown on show action
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    $showMapper
       ->add('name')
       ->add('price')
       ->add('isVisible')
   ;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your boolean field to your entity

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="bool")
     */
    protected $is_visible;
```

and add the field to your admin form mapper and set apropriate field type,
for example:

```
$formMapper
            ->add('is_visible', 'bool', array(
                'label' => 'Title'
            ))
```

If no type is specified, SonataAdminBundle tries to guess it.
[Documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/getting_started.html)

Also, you can generate Admin class from existing entity:

```
php app/console sonata:admin:generate YourNS/FooBundle/Entity/Bar
```

The ***sonata:admin:generate*** command generates a new Admin class based on the given model class, registers it as a service and potentially creates a new controller. As an argument you need to specify the fully qualified model class. All passed arguments and options are used as default values in interactive mode. You can disable the interactive mode with --no-interaction option.

Options are:

**bundle**: the bundle name (the default value is determined by the given model
class, e.g. “YourNSFooBundle”)

**admin**: the admin class basename (by default this adds “Admin” to the model class name, e.g. “BarAdmin”)

**controller**: the controller class basename (by default this adds “AdminController” to the model class name, e.g. “BarAdminController”)

**manager**: the model manager type (by default this is the first registered model manager type, e.g. “orm”)

**services**: the services YAML file (the default value is “services.yml” or “admin.yml” if it already exist)

**id**: the admin service ID (the default value is combination of the bundle name and admin class basename like “your_ns_foo.admin.bar”)

Comment: This might be a foolish question, but, can i use this approach while EDITING the existing entity src/Application/Sonata/NewsBundle/Entity/Post.php and then follow the steps you provided in the answer, generating Admin class and so on? Thank you very much.

Comment: An Admin class represents the mapping of your model to each administration action. In it, you decide which fields to show on a listing, which to use as filters or what to show in a creation or edition form.

Comment: Sorry for kepping asking stupid questions, but i thjink i got it all wrong...
---
> You have to add your boolean field to your entity

**Where i should add this field?** Let's say I have a fresh install of [Sonata Admin's sandbox](https://sonata-project.org/get-started). The web app is working fine using default settings.
---
> and add the field to your admin form mapper and set apropriate field type

**Where** i should do this?